# Spring MVC разное пространство для разных пользоваталей

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, mvc, java-ee

Есть небольшой сервис написанный на Spring MVC. Условно пользователь делает некую выборку, которая добавляется в `ArrayList`, если залогиниться под другим пользователем, то мы увидим именно то, что делал предыдущий юзер.

Т.е. проблема в том, что фактически существует одно рабочее пространство на всех.

Как создать отдельное пространство для каждого юзера?

Comment: Есть интерфейс _javax.servlet.http.HttpSession_, в котором определены методы `setAttribute(String name, Object value)` и `getAttribute(String name)`.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону @Scope для компонентов. Еще возможно вы храните ArrayList не там где нужно. Не совсем понятно из вопроса что делается с выборкой после добавление в коллекцию.

Comment: Выборка показывается пользователю. Как пример - корзина интерне-магазина - для каждого своя.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы юзер мог делать выборку только для себя, то надо добавить его в саму выборку. Таким образом вы сможете создать пространство для юзера, потому что другой юзер будет делать то же самое и то, что касается одного, не может пересекаться с другим. Конечно это работает до тех пор, пока вы не станете джойнить результаты выборки.